# issues updating records in ssis using lookup and oledb command

Tags: ssis, azure-sql-database

im working on an ssis project loading data between two sql azure databases that is updating matching records and inserting new records between them using a lookup and ole db command but I'm getting an error on the ole db command as the following, any ideas what it may be? trying to update over 20,000 records

[OLE DB Command [28]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.

An OLE DB record is available. Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0" Hresult: 0x80004005 Description: "Communication link failure".

An OLE DB record is available. Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0" Hresult: 0x80004005 Description: "TCP Provider: The semaphore timeout period has expired.

[image: control is setup as follows]

Comment: increase the timeout of your application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like this could be a bug in OLE DB for SSIS. Could [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6961320/5059085) be the one you're looking for?